# Angular -> Put Username from Cookie into Inputfield

Tags: angular, cookies, input, web-applications

I have a Webapplication with oAuth, the Webapplication contains a Inputifeld for the Users loginName.
The Loginname also is in the Cookie from the oAuth.
I now want to get that username from the Cookie and put it into the inputfield so that the User doesen't has to type it in by themselves. But the user should also have the Option to change the Input if he wants to.

**This is my Inputfield:**

```
<div class="input-field-userName">
    <div class="input-field input-oneline center-block" data-init="auto" style="width: 20%;">
      <input
        [formControlName]="homeForm.Username"
        [name]="homeForm.Username"
        type="text"
        id="userName"
        placeholder="userName"
        ngModel pattern="^t\w{4,9}$">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hope you are using reactive forms, during the form initialization you can read the cookie value and set the default value for username

Comment: Yeah I do use reactive forms, but i havent found an example how to do it online. But i will try.

Comment: you can refer this stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the default value during initialization of the form . The default username can be read from cookie

```
`registerForm = new FormGroup({
 userName: new FormControl('alvic'),  // add default value
 `
```